# Flutter: How to fix height design?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Hi how to change the height to be the same. In my situation Blood Pressure and Body Temperature are not at the same height. Can refer to the arrow I have made.

Code:

```
Container(
                                  child: Container(
                                    color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: [
                                            Column(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                              children: [
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  height: 10,
                                                ),
                                                _bloodPressureLatest.isNotEmpty
                                                    ? bloodPressureLatest(
                                                        context,
                                                        checkBloodPressureReadingStatus(double.parse(
                                                            _bloodPressureLatest[0]
                                                                    ["bloodPressure"]
                                                                ["systolic"])),
                                                        _bloodPressureLatest[0]
                                                                    ["bloodPressure"]
                                                                ["systolic"] ??
                                                            "0",
                                                        _bloodPressureLatest[0]
                                                                    ["bloodPressure"]
                                                                ["diastolic"] ??
                                                            "0",
                                                        _bloodPressureLatest[0][
                                                                "recordTimestamp"] ??
                                                            _timestamp)
                                                    : bloodPressureLatest(
                                                        context,
                                                        0,
                                                        "0",
                                                        "0",
                                                        _timestamp),
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  height: 10,
                                                ),
                                                _heartRateLatest.isNotEmpty
                                                    ? heartRateLatest(
                                                        context,
                                                        _heartRateLatest,
                                                        _heartRateLatest[0]
                                                            ["vitalValue"],
                                                        _heartRateLatest[0]
                                                            ["recordTimestamp"])
                                                    : heartRateLatest(context,
                                                        [], "0", _timestamp),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              height: 10,
                                              width: 30,
                                            ),
                                            Column(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                              children: [
                                                _bodyTemperatureLatest
                                                        .isNotEmpty
                                                    ? bodyTemperatureLatest(
                                                        context,
                                                        checkBodyTemperatureReadingStatus(
                                                            double.parse(
                                                                _bodyTemperatureLatest[
                                                                        0][
                                                                    "vitalValue"])),
                                                        _bodyTemperatureLatest[
                                                            0]["vitalValue"],
                                                        _bodyTemperatureLatest[
                                                                0]
                                                            ["recordTimestamp"])
                                                    : bodyTemperatureLatest(
                                                        context,
                                                        0,
                                                        "0",
                                                        _timestamp),
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  height: 10,
                                                ),
                                                _bmiLatest.isNotEmpty
                                                    ? bmiLatest(
                                                        context,
                                                        checkBmiReadingStatus(
                                                            double.parse(
                                                                _bmiLatest[0][
                                                                    "vitalValue"])),
                                                        _bmiLatest[0]["weight"]
                                                            .toString(),
                                                        _bmiLatest[0]["height"]
                                                            .toString(),
                                                        _bmiLatest[0]
                                                            ["recordTimestamp"])
                                                    : bmiLatest(context, 0, "0",
                                                        "0", _timestamp),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
```

I have put the Sized Box to set the height and also entered the margin in the container but still can't solve this problem. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution, you can pop the code in dartpad. The trick is to add  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, in the row.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ElevatedCard1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const ElevatedCard1({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Card(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          child: Center(child: Text('Elevated Card')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ElevatedCard2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const ElevatedCard2({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Card(
        child: SizedBox(
      
          height: 300,
          child: Center(child: Text('Elevated Card')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.deepOrange,
      child: Column(children: [
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
          Expanded(child: Column(children: const [
            ElevatedCard1(),
            ElevatedCard1(),
          ]),),
          Expanded(child: Column(children: const [
            ElevatedCard2(),
           ElevatedCard1(),
          ]),),
        ])
    ],),);
  }
}
```

[image]